# Automatically byte-compiling on save

Tags: emacs, save, elisp, bytecode

Everytime I save a file in emacs lisp mode, I want it to be automatically byte-compiled. Can someone come up with a function that does `byte-compile-file` on the current file if the current major mode is emacs lisp mode? I want to `add-hook` that function to `after-save-hook`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer [here](http://www-tsujii.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~yoshinag/tips/junk_elisp.html#bytecompile). The following does it all. It is a copy from the linked site.

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 
          (lambda ()
            (if (eq major-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode)
                (save-excursion (byte-compile-file buffer-file-name)))))
```